# Display Inline Images in HTML EMail Django

Tags: python, django, html-email

I am trying to display images inline in Djano while sending HTML Email. I have the HTML Email working. But the images are displayed as an attachment, i followed the steps in https://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2014/01/15/sending-emails-with-embedded-images-in-django/ to display image as attachment. Which i do not want. I want the image to be displayed inline.

In my Django Template i have :

```
<img src="/static/url/location/image.png" />
```

The urls.py has the right setting. When i go to :

```
http://localhost:8000/static/url/location/image.png
```

i can see the image clearly.

When the email is sent, the image is not displayed and i do not know why. Any help is kindly appreciated.

I am using Django 1.6.2 btw.

EDIT: Implemented the suggestions given below about using Absolute URL. 
I did try the absolute URL. Weird part is : When i used a absolute url of some other site, For ex:

```
<img src="google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"; />
```

the images are displayed inline. When i use the absolute url location of image on my local server, the image is not displayed :-(. Not sure what else i am missing.

Comment: You need to use absolute URLs with images in HTML emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need an absolute url to the image on a server. Cannot reference relative images in an email as far as I know.

You could do this for an absolute url to the current host:

```
<img src="{{ request.get_host }}/static/url/location/image.png" />
```

You could probably benefit from using the `{% static %}` tag as well, (if you have static files configured correctly) like this:

```
<img src="{{ request.get_host }}{% static 'url/location/image.png' %}" />
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help. I did try the absolute URL. Weird part is : When i used a absolute url of some other site, For ex: <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /> , the images are displayed inline. When i use the absolute url location of image on my local server, the image is not displayed :-(. Not sure what else i am missing.

Comment: Your email client must not be able to connect to your local server. I can't think of anything else. Can you confirm the correct url is in the image tag?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I printed the actual url value in the template, to make sure its the right URL. I think you are right about email client not having access to url. Looks like i have to upload the images on a public server for it to be visible on emails.